# How can i remove these blank spaces in html classes for production in nextjs?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

How can I remove these blank spaces in production? I'm using nextjs with tailwindcss and this happens because I format my code to be more organized with the elements' classes.

How code looks in production

[image: 1]

How I format my code

[image: 2]

Comment: have you disabled prettier? to see if it's from prettier or tailwind or another extension.

Comment: @aryankarim i format classes that way, isn't a prettier or tailwind problem i think, just how nextjs builds for production, surely there is some configuration for that

Comment: I don't think manually formatting those classes is a good idea. Try to use a prettier or an extension that does that for you. https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/10918 check this! it might help.

Comment: @aryankarim that doesn't solve my problem, but thanks

Comment: You can remove the whitespaces by not manually adding them in your code. If you want more readable class names you can always extract them into a utility class, see https://tailwindcss.com/docs/reusing-styles#extracting-classes-with-apply.